# How to rename file in Multer middleware to data I am sending in request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, file-rename

On a frontend I am generating unique ID for every order. Idea is to rename file which user uploads to **orderId**.
Here is my request to server:

```
   const handleFileUpload = e => {
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append("pdf-file", e.target.files[0])
      formData.append("orderId", orderId)

      axios.post("http://localhost:8000/upload", formData, { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } })
         .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
         })
         .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
         })
   }
```

Here is the server code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, "./uploads")
   },
   filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      console.log(req.body)
      cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${req.body.orderId}`)
   }
})

const uploadStorage = multer({storage: storage})

app.post("/upload", uploadStorage.single("pdf-file"), (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body)
   return res.send("file upload")
})
```

`console.log(req.body)` shows **empty object** in `filename` and **orderId** in `app.post()`.
Here is how it looks:

```
[Object: null prototype] {} // inside filename
[Object: null prototype] { orderId: 'e923920b-fdf0-41ab-97dd-2fcf20b57250' } // inside app.post()
```

So this cannot be done as far as I understand inside **filename**. How to deal with this situation? And is this even possible?

Comment: first save upload file  then return path store file to your controller  after that rename file  and update table store path in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do, is to change order I am appending to formData.

Now this works:

```
formData.append("orderId", orderId)
formData.append("pdf-file", e.target.files[0])
```